# Create a scatterplot where color corresponds to a variable with multiple values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

I have the following dataframe **`df`**, where the variable **`types`** corresponds to up to 3 types for each ID (the dataset has approximately 3000 rows):

```
ID   types  grade  num 
a01  a,b,c   7.1    1 
a02  c,d     7.7    3   
a03  c       7.3    4   
a04  a,c,f   7.9    5   
a05  a,c,e   6.7    3
```

I want to create a scatterplot, where the x axis corresponds to the **`num`** column, the y axis corresponds to the **`grade`** and the color of each point corresponds to its type, similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWmVK.png

However, since **`types`** has more than one value, I'm struggling to plot it. If types only had one type, I know I could simply do `geom_point(aes(colour = types))`, but since it can have up to 3, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like `tidyr::separate_rows` which by default will split the column in question into multiple rows for each separate value it detects.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  separate_rows(types) %>%
  ggplot(aes(num, grade, color = types)) +
  # geom_point() + # points are overplotted
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1)
```

Or more minimally:

```
  ggplot(tidyr::separate_rows(df, types), aes(num, grade, color = types)) +
  # geom_point() + # points are overplotted
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jon Spring's answer is a good fast way to get your data visualized.

I think I would start with what you want to actually see in your plot (I wasn't sure when I read your question). Do you want points that share types (like all "a, c" points) to be colored the same? Or do you want them to be duplicated so that they show up in 'a' color and 'c' color on the same point? Jitter or changing alpha levels are good ways to make overlapping points actually show up in the vis.

Because your y values are .1 apart, but your x values are 1 apart, you might change the jitter setting so that it only jitters along the x axis. And then set alpha levels to .5 or .35 even to accommodate overplotting?

`geom_jitter(width = 0.1, alpha=.5)`

It seems like there's a lot of data to fit into one vis, so you might try a facet wrap instead to see if it makes the graphs more readable.

`+facet_wrap(~types)`